# Extracting single Text from a table cell containing multiple texts Robot Framework

Tags: jquery, python, python-2.7, xpath, robotframework

I have a table in which some cells have multiple text and each text has its own xpath. An example, the two text elements in the code below are located in the same table cell, but has two xpaths : for the first "B17AA038" xpath is //*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[10]/text() and the next instance has another xpath (//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[10]/div[2]/text()). In the table I have some cells that have many individual text elements packed in one cell. I am trying to select one particular text element from the cell and use it as variable , but so far failed.

as an example, I tried this:

```
Run keyword if  '${Row_No}'=='1'    get text    xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[${Table_Row}]/td[10]/text()
```

and got this error message:

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

The related html is as follows:

```
<td style="word-wrap: break-word; min-width: 120px; max-width: 120px; white-space:nowrap;">

                                            <!-- sample level pandh_id-->

                                                <!-- test level pandh_id-->

                                                        **B17AA03**8&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-info" style="background-color: white; color:black; border:1px solid #808080; margin-bottom:2px; font-size:0.5em;">2</span>
                                                        <!-- hidden print div for add test to this sample-->
                                                        <div class="hidden-print" style="padding-bottom:1.275em; padding-right:3em;">
                                                            <a href="/research_add_test/CS16EB/IN428A/R17AA038?subject_uuid=sub3c968403c0f248a89442b99ccca91fb4&amp;external_case_id=sfdgsfdg&amp;external_subject_id=sfgdsfdg&amp;subject_id=RS1001&amp;page=1&amp;study_id=pandh_ST_1&amp;some_list=Proband&amp;some_list=None" style="text-decoration:none" title="order another test to this sample">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:12px;"></i>
                                                                <i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                            </a>

                                                        </div>
                                                     <!-- if it has more than 1-->
                                                 <!-- if sample pandh id and test pandh id matches-->

                                                <!-- test level pandh_id-->





                                                        <div class="hidden-print" style="padding-bottom:2.575em; visibility:hidden;">
                                                            **B17AA038**
                                                        </div>
                                                     <!-- if it has more than 1-->
                                                 <!-- if sample pandh id and test pandh id matches-->
                                             <!-- test level loop-->
                                         <!-- sample level loop-->
                                    </td>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [This discussion](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5459) might be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error implies, the `get text` keyword requires a locator that results in an *element*, not the text of an element. In essence, you are asking selenium to get the text of the text of an element.

The solution is to remove the `text()` from the locator:

```
xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[${Table_Row}]/td[10]
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, sorry to bother you again. Well, in the next cell I have texts ranging from 'xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/text()[1]' to 'xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/text()[11]' . In this case I am stuck again. I tried by using   'xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/text()[1]', failed then tried  'xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/[1]' and also  'xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/text[1]' but no success. What is your suggestion?

Comment: @nhrcpt: my suggestion is that if you have another question, click the "Ask Question" button. The comment section is not a place to post code and ask additional questions.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for the suggestion. Although related to this particular topic, I have done as you advised. Appreciate if you can check and let me know there is any workaround.