# Selecting one text from a table cell that has multiple value in it . Followup on on Robot Framework

Tags: jquery, python, html, robotframework

This is a followup question of the question:  [Extracting single Text from a table cell containing multiple texts Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928572/extracting-single-text-from-a-table-cell-containing-multiple-texts-robot-framewo/45928670?noredirect=1#comment78816907_45928670)

The problem is I have a table that has many different data(texts) in one cell. I am trying to select a particular texts from that cell. All the text elements have different xpath, but I am having trouble to extract them. In the attached image, The values are extracted from two rows only. First two rows of data are actually in one table row and the rest data are in the 2nd row. I need to extract only one of the texts from a particular position and to use that as variable.

[image: In this image, The first two dates are in the same cell. The bottom 4 dates are in one cell.]

As per feedback from a kind user, I have removed text() part from the code and it worked fine when a cell has only one text. But in other cases I have multiple texts stacked into the same cell. As example, in one cell I have texts ranging from `'xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/text()‌​[1]'` to `'xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/text()‌​[11]'` .
 In this case I am stuck again. I tried by using `

```
${text}=   Get Text  'xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/text()‌​[1]'`
```

This was failed then tried using `'xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/[1]'` and also `'xpath=//*[@id="profile_research"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[10]/text[1‌​]`' but all failed. Kindly suggest how to extract the text.

Update: The html code are as follows:

```
<td style="word-wrap: break-word; min-width: 120px; max-width: 120px; white-space:nowrap;">

         B17AA022&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-info" style="background-color: white; color:black; border:1px solid #808080; margin-bottom:2px; font-size:0.5em;">2</span>
         <div class="hidden-print" style="padding-bottom:1.275em; padding-right:3em;">
             <a href="/research_add_test/CSEBF7/IN25C2/B17AA022?some_list=main&amp;some_list=M&amp;external_case_id=Ext_ID_RCI&amp;subject_id=RS1000&amp;page=1&amp;subject_uuid=sub0d9b086c0b5243ea990933d3f3f8a503&amp;study_id=pandh_ST_1&amp;external_subject_id=External+Subject+RCI" style="text-decoration:none" title="order another test to this sample">
             </a>

         </div>
         <div class="hidden-print" style="padding-bottom:2.575em; visibility:hidden;">
             B17AA022
         </div>

         B17AA030&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-info" style="background-color: white; color:black; border:1px solid #808080; margin-bottom:2px; font-size:0.5em;">2</span>
         <div class="hidden-print" style="padding-bottom:1.275em; padding-right:3em;">
             <a href="/research_add_test/CSEBF7/IN25C2/B17AA030?some_list=main&amp;some_list=M&amp;external_case_id=Ext_ID_RCI&amp;subject_id=RS1000&amp;page=1&amp;subject_uuid=sub0d9b086c0b5243ea990933d3f3f8a503&amp;study_id=pandh_ST_1&amp;external_subject_id=External+Subject+RCI" style="text-decoration:none" title="order another test to this sample">
             </a>

         </div>

         <div class="hidden-print" style="padding-bottom:2.575em; visibility:hidden;">
             B17AA039
         </div>
```

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to suggest a working xpath without knowing the structure of the html.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the html codes as you suggested.

Comment: This would be much easier to read if you fixed the indentation and removed all of the comments, and perhaps remove all of the attributes that don't affect the parsing of the data.

Comment: Hi, I have removed the comments .